# Update Manage (mintupdate) show nothing without sudo

Tags: linux-mint, sudo

I use Linux Mint 18.2. Some time ago tried manually update Linux kernel. 
It was unsuccessful and I rolled back on previous kernel version, but faced with issue that Update Manage not work any more:
It launches but show empty list. But if I start it with sudo it works.

I tried to purge it in install again, but it does not help.

How to make it works without sudo again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:
file `/etc/apt/sources.list` have no read permission for Others. After adding it become work.